# How do I get a registry value in Inno Setup when the value only uses the default name?

Tags: windows, registry, inno-setup, pascal

I'm trying to get the install directory of an application from the Windows Registry (Google Sketchup in this case) with Inno Setup's Pascal scripting so I can install a plugin there.

The registry key doesn't have a name, it just has "(Default)" in Regedit.

I tried this:

```
RegQueryStringValue( HKLM, 'SOFTWARE\Google\Google Sketchup 6', '(Default)', pluginLoc );
```

but it doesn't return a value. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Just leave the `SubKeyName` empty, like so:

```
[Code]
function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
var
  V: string;
begin
  if RegQueryStringValue(HKLM, 'SOFTWARE\Google\Google Sketchup 6', '', V) then
    MsgBox('Value is "' + V + '"', mbInformation, MB_OK);
  Result := TRUE;
end;
```

The matching documentation for the underlying API call is for *[RegQueryValueEx()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724911(VS.85).aspx)*, which states:

> The name of the registry value.
>
> If lpValueName is NULL or an empty string, "", the function retrieves the type and data for the key's unnamed or default value, if any.

Comment: It is the `ValueName`, not the `SubKeyName` which need to be empty.