# How to detect which MS-Access 2010 runtime is installed?

Tags: ms-access

there are two [access runtimes](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10910) provided by microsoft. 
a x86 and x64 version - unfortunately a x64 runtime version can't open 32bit mde-files and vice versa.

What is the easiest way to detect which runtime is installed?

My favorite way is asking the registry.

The way described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203980/detect-whether-office-2010-is-32bit-or-64bit-via-the-registry) doesn't work, because access-runtime doesn't create the outlook registry key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem on this way:

from registry HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\Access.Application.14\shell\Open\Command
from the default key i get the path to the msaccess.exe (Version 2010).

then i open that file with the [ImageLoad](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680209%28VS.85%29.aspx) function.
in the returning structure i read the machine field.

[LOADED_IMAGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680349%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).[FileHeader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680336%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).[FileHeader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680313%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).Machine

Answer (score 0):

I found [this link](http://community.installshield.com/showthread.php?t=201524) but I don't know if it is fail proof.  This registry key exists when 64 bit Access is installed.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Access Connectivity Engine\InstallRoot
```

Comment: One possible fail is, if the os is XP. then the key is also there because there is no wow64 :-(