# Detect whether MS Office installed is 32bit or 64bit by using registry

Tags: wix, registry, ms-office, vsto, add-in

I want to install vsto addin based on the excel version (32 bit or 64 bit).
I am planning to bundle both 32bit and 64 bit msis and install one by determining the excel version.
I am able to find this link to detect whether 2010 office is 32 bit or 64 bit by using registry.
[Detect whether Office is 32bit or 64bit via the registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203980/detect-whether-office-2010-is-32bit-or-64bit-via-the-registry)
But i want to check for excel 2007 and 2013 whether they are 32 bit or 64 bit.
Is it possible to detect them via registry.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, look for the installed version of Outlook in this key:

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Outlook.Application\CurVer

The value will be Outlook.Application.15 (for 2013).  Then parse that value to get the integer and lookup this key:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Outlook

If it exists, check the value of Bitness to determine if it is 32-bit (x86) or 64-bit (x64). If it doesn't exist, assume 32-bit.

Answer (score 4):

Given: Office32 is installed into "Program Files (x86)", this works for me.

I basically check to see if winword.exe is somewhere below the key.  If they don't install the word part, well, tough at this point.  I use this to variably run 32-bit or 64-bit msi installers for office.

```
<Fragment>
<Property Id="IS_32BITOFFICE">
  <DirectorySearch Path="[ProgramFilesFolder]\Microsoft Office"                  
                   Depth="4"                   
                   AssignToProperty="no"                   
                   Id="IS_32BIT_OFFICE_DIRSEARCH">
    <FileSearch   Name="winword.exe" />
  </DirectorySearch>
</Property>

<ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
  <Component Id="WIN64_OFFICE32_MSI">
    <File Id="WIN64_OFFICE32_MSI" src="WIN64_OFFICE32.txt"/>
    <Condition>IS_32BITOFFICE</Condition>
  </Component> 
  <Component Id="WIN64_OFFICE64_MSI">
    <File Id="WIN64_OFFICE64_MSI" src="WIN64_OFFICE64.txt"/>
    <Condition>NOT IS_32BITOFFICE</Condition>
  </Component> 
    </ComponentGroup>
</Fragment>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't reliably detect it from registry (direct call). Better is to create Custom installer module in C# or VB.net, fetch ProductCode of application. From product code, you can get the Bitness.

Product code is also fetched from registry, but let Office application handle it.

```
Private IsExcel32Bit As Boolean = False
Private IsExcel64Bit As Boolean = False
Private ReadOnly STR_prdCodeDelimeter As Char = CChar("-")

Private Sub GetExcelBitness(ByVal exApp As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application)
    Dim prdCode As String = exApp.ProductCode
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(prdCode) AndAlso CInt(prdCode.Split(STR_prdCodeDelimeter)(3)(0).ToString) = 0 Then
        IsExcel32Bit = True
    ElseIf Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(prdCode) AndAlso CInt(prdCode.Split(STR_prdCodeDelimeter)(3)(0).ToString) = 1 Then
        IsExcel64Bit = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Btw keeping both installer separately is going to help you in future. Sometimes product code might be null or wrong if MS Office is not installed properly.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the product code (GUID) to identify the bitness of Office applications. See [How to detect whether installed MS Office 2010 is 32 or 64 bit](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/43499ae0-bcb5-4527-8edb-f5a955987b56/how-to-detect-whether-installed-ms-office-2010-is-32-or-64-bit?forum=worddev) for more information.

Comment: I want to find bitness for office 2013 applications.

Comment: The same can be applied to Office 2013.