# Detect whether Office 2013 is 32 bit or 64 bit via registry

Tags: registry, ms-office, 32bit-64bit, office-2013

Is there any way to find installed microsoft office 2013 bitness(64 bit or 32 bit) by checking a registry value?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect whether MS Office installed is 32bit or 64bit by using registry](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27900574/detect-whether-ms-office-installed-is-32bit-or-64bit-by-using-registry)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the product code (GUID) to identify the bitness of Office applications. See [How to detect whether installed MS Office 2010 is 32 or 64 bit](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/43499ae0-bcb5-4527-8edb-f5a955987b56/how-to-detect-whether-installed-ms-office-2010-is-32-or-64-bit?forum=worddev) for more information.