# How to import Winsock in registry file

Tags: excel, vba, winsock

I like to use winsock in EXCEL VBA. So far I found quite good instruction in this stackoverflow question, [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65528189/how-to-use-winsock-control-in-excel-vba). I did every step except number three, since I did not know what it meant. Nevertheless, I could load the Microsoft Winsock Control 6.0 bib. Then I tried the following code, using a new document, and I added an userfrom and a command button.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim winsock As MSWinsockLib.winsock
    Set winsock = New MSWinsockLib.winsock
    
    winsock.Connect "localhost", 5100
End Sub
```

But "Set winsock = New MSWinsockLib.winsock" causes a run time error, to precise run-time error 429 "ActiveX component can't create object".  Is this because I did not copy the license, as described in the original post? And if yes, how do I do this? I should add, that I am using a 32 bit version of EXCEL.

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to describe the problem you're having or question you're asking. If you remove the tags (which shouldn't be in the title at all), it leaves *using in*, which clearly is meaningless. Your title should be clear and descriptive enough that a future site user skimming a list of search results will know what it contains. For suggestions on writing a good title, see [ask].